# How to create same file in all subdirectories?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, filesystems, touch

I have many existing subdirectories, like:

```
/path/to/my/subs/a
/path/to/my/subs/b
/path/to/my/subs/c
```

No I want to create a new file in each of them. The filename is constant, like:

```
/path/to/my/subs/a/foo.md
/path/to/my/subs/b/foo.md
/path/to/my/subs/c/foo.md
```

How do I do this? I hoped `touch /path/to/my/subs/*/foo.md` would do but it said `touch: /path/to/my/subs/*/foo.md: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use `bash` as your shell then use brace expansion.

```
touch /path/to/my/subs/{a,b,c}/foo.md
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` utility:

```
find /path/to/my/subs -type d -links 2 -exec touch "{}/foo.md" \;
```

This will walk the whole tree starting at subs, locate leaf (terminal) directories, and touch a foo md file there.

You can also omit the "-exec"... part and use `xargs` to create the files all together at the end, spawning less `touch` binaries, or use a single touch:

```
touch $( find /path/to/my/subs -type d -links 2 | sed -e 's#$#/foo.md#g' )
```

The `find` part will get the directories, `sed` will turn them into the appropriate file names.

If you have a single layer of directories:

for dir in /path/to/my/subs/*; do touch $dir/foo.md ; done